# setTint not working

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar

I have a been looking around to change the tint of my UINavigationBar on iOS 5.1.

I have a UITabBarController with two UINavigationControllers attached, the following code is placed in the custom UINavigationController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

...but this does not have any effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have subclassed `UINavigationController` (and not having a `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` which is most common) then you should do this instead:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

because `self` is already a navigation controller. Otherwise your code you would have worked just fine (ie You had a `UIViewController` or one of its subclasses and you've embedded it via code or via Interface Builder into a `UINavigationController`)

Answer (score 0):

try this

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
  }